# How can i query data from a table in Ms Access in my SQL server 2005 stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

How can i query data from a table in Ms Access in my SQL server 2005 stored procedure ?

Comment: see `OPENROWSET()`... or... move the data to Sql!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example syntax [from here](http://syntaxhelp.com/SQLServer/OPENDATASOURCE)

```
SELECT * FROM 
OpenDataSource( 
    'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Data Source="c:\temp\payroll.mdb";
    User ID=Admin;Password=;')...employees
```

I think `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` or `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0` might be preferred to Jet though.

Comment: Which is preferable depends on the format of the data file. If it's MDB, you need to use Jet, no matter what version.